# How to change a class public variable permanently later on throughout my code in C#

Tags: c#, public

I want to create variables in a choose your own adventure/path game where I can access a public 'Class" full of variables and change them throughout the story in order to also change stat points money etcetera.

```
{
    class playerCharacter
    {
        public string playerClass = "Unknown";
    }
    class displayNumbers
    {
        public int healthPlayer = 50;
        public int magicPlayer = 20;
        public int staminaPlayer = 50;
        public int reputationPlayer = 10;
        public int persuasionPlayer = 10;
        public int charmPlayer = 10;
    }
}
```

So I create my classes storing information. now later on in the code, I want to change that information then display that info like so.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use properties for your data instead of fields as you have them now. So your healthPlayer in the DisplayNumbers class would become:

```cs
public int HealthPlayer { get; set; } = 50;
```

and then when you create an instance of the displayNumbers like this:

```cs
var nums = new DisplayNums();
```

And then to access the property you can do this:

```cs
// get the value
var value = nums.HealthPlayer;

// set a new value
nums.HealthPlayer = 40;
```

This is the standard simple view of properties, but I recommend you do a deep dive into fields vs. properties in c# and get very familiar with both, along with the coding conventions and use cases that they apply to.

If you haven't already, [dig in to the official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for help. If you aren't familiar with the docs I strongly recommend that you get used to looking there first and then finding use cases from blogs and other sources for context if needed. The docs are *usually* pretty well maintained and current to the latest language specs and features, and outline best practices also.

Comment: I did what you said but when I use my display attributes function after setting it. It still displays the orignal set number